# Bind folders in .img to folders outside of it?

Tags: fstab

Is there a way to bind folders located in an `.img` file to folders outside it?

To be more specific, supposing there's Ubuntu installed in `img` file, I want the image's `fstab` to bind a few folders outside the `img` file.

That is to say the binding must be done from within the image. So if I save anything in one of the binded folders, it will save outside the image without taking up the space assigned to the `img`.

Comment: How is Ubuntu running from the `img`?

Comment: I can make it run using KVM, but my goal is to use GRUB and boot into it.

Comment: Is this a standard ubuntu install or some-sort of customised install?  If its a customised image, you probably want to do some-sort of nfs-sharing/mounting in the img (or iso) customised image ... this is beyond my knowledge though on how to produce a customised image, hence this comment - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

Comment: @fossfreedom, that isn't an option, as I plan to be able to boot into the `img` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not. The Linux is just a series of files. Devices are files and your `img` is just a file on a device. Mount the device, then the image on the device and then bind-mount the locations inside the mounted `img`. Simples.

```
UUID=your_device_UUID    /media/disk    ext4    errors=remount-ro    0    1
/media/disk/image.img    /mnt/img       auto    defaults             0    0
/mnt/img/deep-location   /mnt/deep      none    bind
```

The targets (second column) need to exist so you will have to do some `sudo mkdir` (drop the sudo if you're mounting inside your home). The locations are completely up to you. Use `/mnt/` for mounting things you don't want to show up as devices in `naultilus` and use `/media/` for things that you *do* want to show up.

Oh and on the second mount, you might have to switch `auto` for the actual filesystem of the image.

Comment: No, I mean bind from within the Ubuntu in the `img`. The binding I'm looking for should be done by the Ubuntu inside.

Comment: No, I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Perhaps you could edit the question to give an example of what should be where.

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

edit `/etc/rc.local` and make an entry like:

`sudo mount /dev/sdaX /home/user`

Comment: If I boot into the `img`, there isn't going to be any other operating system to manage the share.

Comment: Now I got it. I will think in a solution.

Comment: Maybe mounting with script that runs at startup?

Comment: Yes but, how can I get it to detect the filesystem outside in the first place?

Comment: After the boot, what is the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but to be honest, I'm trying to course my action before doing it. I still have to find out how to set up GRUB in an empty USB first.